# Rhino Mocks Error: Previous method 'IEnumerator.MoveNext();' requires a return value or an exception to throw

Tags: .net, unit-testing, c#-4.0, rhino-mocks

I have the following test code:

```
parentViewModel = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IParentViewModel>();
parentViewModel.Expect(x => x.GetPropertyValue<IEnumerable<Milestone>>("JobMilestones")).Return(new Milestone[0]);

viewModel = new JobPenaltiesViewModel(j, new Penalty[0], _opContext, parentViewModel);

Assert.That(viewModel.Milestones.Count(), Is.EqualTo(0));
parentViewModel.VerifyAllExpectations();

List<string> propsChanged = new List<string>();
viewModel.PropertyChanged += (s, e) => propsChanged.Add(e.PropertyName);

parentViewModel.Raise(x => x.PropertyChanged += null, parentViewModel, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("JobMilestones"));

AssertPropertiesChangedAsExepected(propsChanged, 1, "Milestones");

Milestone m1 = GenerateMilestone(j);
List<Milestone> milestones1 = new List<Milestone> { m1 };
parentViewModel.Expect(x => x.GetPropertyValue<IEnumerable<Milestone>>("JobMilestones")).Return(milestones1).Repeat.Any();

IEnumerable<Milestone> milestones = viewModel.Milestones;
Assert.That(milestones.Count(), Is.EqualTo(1));
parentViewModel.VerifyAllExpectations();
```

All the tests and assertions succeed up until the:

```
Assert.That(milestones.Count(), Is.EqualTo(1));
```

That's where I get the exception:

```
Previous method 'IEnumerator.MoveNext();' requires a return value or an exception to throw.
```

I've tried everything I can think of, and my testing seems to indicate that the parentViewModel Mock is returning null, or an empty enumeration (i.e. when I use the debugger to inspect the returned value the 'Results View' says the enumeration returned no results).

What am I missing here?

Comment: Do you get the correct result if you try to do: `IEnumerable<Milestone> milestones = parentViewModel.Milestones;` and `Assert.That(milestones.Count(), Is.EqualTo(1))`? (Just verify where you loose m1)

Comment: No, the `Assert.That(milestones.Count(), Is.EqualTo(1))` is the source of the exception.  I never get to the `parentViewModel.VerifyAllExpectations()`

Comment: Ok, I it was not very clear what I meant. I meant adding the lines just after `parentViewModel.Expect(x => x.GetPropertyValue<IEnumerable<Milestone>>("JobMilestones")).Return(milestones1).Repeat.Any();` so you assert on `parentViewModel` before asserting on `viewModel`. To verify that `m1` is in `parentViewModel.JobMileStones` (I wrote parentViewModel.MileStones in the first comment - my bad.).

Comment: This gives me: `This action is invalid when the mock object ... is in record state.`  I'm not sure why it's complaining that I'm in record mode, I'm using AAA syntax.  Do I need to somehow reset the Mock before I attempt to return a second value?

Comment: I've actually now removed that section of code; upon further review I realized that it isn't adding anything to my test.  What I really want to test here is that when the parent notifies that its "JobMilestones" collection has changed, that the child notifies that its "Milestones" collection has changed.  However, I would still like to understand this problem, so if anyone can answer it, I'll gladly award the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've since removed the offending code; however I never did figure out why it was behaving the way it was.

Answer (score 2):

`milestones.Count()` is executing like that (as this is an IEnumerable object):

1. Set counter to 0.
2. Get the first element.
3. Add 1 to the counter.
4. Move to the next element.
5. Step 3 until next element is null
6. Return the counter

So I suggest you to get some rewriting.

Option 1:

1. Create not IEnumerable collection, but some stronger object, like `List` or `Array`:

   `var milestones = viewModel.Milestones.ToArray();

   //var milestones = viewModel.Milestones.ToList();`

   After that you can use  respectively `Count` and `Length` property for the `Assert` check:

   `Assert.That(milestones.Count, Is.EqualTo(1));

   //Assert.That(milestones.Length, Is.EqualTo(1));`
2. Create a local variable to store count parameter:

   `var count = viewModel.Milestones.Count(); // .Count() method executes here.
   Assert.That(count, Is.EqualTo(1));`

Comment: I understand what you're saying, and it makes some sense.  But the question I still have is that the call to the `parentViewModel` should be returning a real `List<>` object (notice the `Expect` call).  So the call to `Count()` shouldn't even need to enumerate it, it should call the Count property on the list.  It's almost as though RhinoMocks is re-writing the return value.

Comment: @Coding Gorilla I must note that you are calling the `.Count()` method of the `IEnumerable<Milestone>`, not the `Count` property of the `List<Milestone>`, so this lead to enumeration of the `IEnumerable<Milestone>`.

Comment: That's not true, the .Count() method is smart enough to figure out if the underly type supports a Count property, and will use that property if it's available.  See the remarks here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535181.aspx

Comment: @Coding Gorilla In the article method `.Count()` is called on `Array` object. In your case you are calling the `IEnumerable<Milestone>.Count()`, because of you made the cast from `List` to the `Ienumerable`. Did you try calling methods like that: `viewModel.Milestones.ToArray().Count()`?

Comment: The underlying type is a `List<>` and the `Count()` method attempts to cast the source as `ICollection` and if that is successful it returns the `Count` property (I decompiled the method to verify this).  So it should not need to actually enumerate the collection.  The debugger, however, showed the underlying type to be a proxy generated (apparently) by RhinoMocks, I guess this is the part I'm not understanding.

Comment: @Coding Gorilla This is called the implicit casting. You set the type of the `milestones` variable to the `IEnumerable<Milestone>`. Since that, the methods of it are calling as it is the `IEnumerable<Milestone>`, not the `List<Milestone>`. And you'll never fall into the `List<Milestone>.Count()` method.